# How to rewrite below urls patterns to specific php files using htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have two dynamic urls which I want to redirect on different php's. Problem is that both urls are dynamic. So it is difficult for me to catch patterns and redirect them.
I search on google and found many examples but all examples url containing some pattern to catch.

Below is the my sample urls along with respective php's.

`https://www.example.com/my-dynnamic-category/my-dynamic-url-id/`   should redirect to `https://www.example.com/detail.php?p=my-dynamic-url-id`

`https://www.example.com/my-dynamic-category/` should redirect to `https://www.example.com/category.php?p=my-dynamic-category`

can anyone please help me.

I tried with below rule for my detail.php redirection,

```
RewriteRule ^\/detail/?$  /detail.php?url=$1$2 [R=301,L]
```

but problem with this rule is that it will work only if url contains word **detail**

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your tried htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown attempts/rules please try following rules in your .htaccess file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Rules for handling https://www.example.com/my-dynamic-category/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ category.php?p=$1 [L]

##Rules for handling https://www.example.com/my-dynnamic-category/my-dynamic-url-id/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ detail.php?p=$2 [L]
```

Comment: First ,Thanks to your quick response. first rule is working fine but this url i e https://www.example.com/my-dynamic-category/ is also redirecting on detail.php

Comment: @lovegoel, its fixed now, could you please edited rules now and let me know if this helps you? Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Nope. Still same thing is happening. If i placed second rule at the first position and first rule on second positon then all patterns redirects to categories.php 
or if i put it as it is then both goes on detail.php

Comment: @lovegoel, could you please do let me know if you have any other rules in your htaccess rile file.

Comment: no, because this is my learning project. so i am pretty sure there is no other rules.

Comment: @lovegoel, could you please do make sure to clear the cache before testing my Rules, I double checked and Rules are working fine for me.

Comment: Yes, i have restarted my local apache web server then checked in to my private browser tab. Both links are redirected to detail.php

Comment: @lovegoel, ok, I have changed rules now, could you please do check my edited Rules once and let me know how it goes?

Comment: Now both links are redirected to category.php

Comment: @lovegoel, ok now I have fixed it, please do check with my edited rules once and let me know how it goes?

Comment: @lovegoel, Your welcome, cheers and happy learning.